# Why did my phone reboot after copying an so file to the system/lib folder?

Tags: adb, mount, system

I ran the following command and the phone automatically rebooted after copying. Why? Was it because the `so` file was in use?

```
$ adb shell 'mount -o rw,remount /system && cp /sdcard/libfoo.so /system/lib'
```

My phone is rooted and enters as root when issued the `adb shell` command. My Android version is 5.1.

I also tried the following commands and the phone still restarted.

```
$ adb remount
remount succeeded
$ adb shell 'cp /sdcard/libfoo.so /system/lib'
```

Comment: What's your Android version and model ? ... sometimes it can be caused by a protection measure that protects the system partition from modifications, it's now why new root programs use "systemless root".   You still have the ability to modify some aspects of the system, but changing files in specific directories can cause problems, this is because systemless root is still in the development stage and has many issue's still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the phone to reboot, push the `so` file directly to the `system/lib` folder. Don't make the `sdcard` folder an intermediary. So you do:

```
$ adb remount
$ adb push libfoo.so /system/lib
```